# How are linux kernel macros used as functions?

Tags: c, linux, macros, kernel, kernel-module

The title of this may sound stupid, but I've never seen something like this before, and I don't really know how else to describe it:

So I just wrote my first kernel module, and I used a linked list, which used the `linux/list.h` header file. In it, there's this macro:

```
400 /**
401  * list_for_each_entry  -       iterate over list of given type
402  * @pos:        the type * to use as a loop cursor.
403  * @head:       the head for your list.
404  * @member:     the name of the list_struct within the struct.
405  */
406 #define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)                          \
407         for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member);      \
408              prefetch(pos->member.next), &pos->member != (head);        \
409              pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member))
```

And, I used it like this (assume `list_head` is the head of the list, and `list` is the `list_struct` within the struct):

```
struct thing *ptr;
list_for_each_entry(ptr, &list_head, list){
        printk(KERN_INFO "contents: %s\n", ptr->something);
}
```

And when I run `dmesg`, there's one line per item in the list...

***So, my question is:*** what is happening here? I haven't seen macros used as if they were functions like this before-- what are the rules for writing a macro that would be called in this way?

I just don't really understand why this works, or how I would write my own macro that worked like this.

Comment: Expand the macro, and you'll see what's happening here.

Comment: Well, I understand what it's doing in that regard. What I don't clearly see is what the rules are for when a macro will loop itself, and when you would call it in the way that I did. It seems to just be some construct that I was previously unaware of -- but I haven't managed to find any explanations anywhere.

Comment: The macro doesn't "loop itself"; it simply expands to a loop construct.  Again, I strongly suggest expanding it out by hand to see this.

Comment: Alright, alright. I will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro simply expands textually. There is no magic going on. You can see the output using `gcc -E`. In this case:

```
#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)                          \
        for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member);      \
             prefetch(pos->member.next), &pos->member != (head);        \
             pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member))

...

struct thing *ptr;
list_for_each_entry(ptr, &list_head, list){
    printk(KERN_INFO "contents: %s\n", ptr->something);
}
```

Expands to:

```
struct thing *ptr;
for (ptr = list_entry((&list_head)->next, typeof(*ptr), list);
     prefetch(ptr->list.next), &ptr->list != (&list_head);
     ptr = list_entry(ptr->list.next, typeof(*ptr), list)) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "contents: %s\n", ptr->something);
}
```

Note that I didn't do any hard work there, I just cut & pasted the code and passed through `gcc -E` (and tidied the formatting slightly).

The looping (as you can see) is done in the expanded code.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see it now. Thank you. I also see what Oli was getting at -- I hadn't yet gone and done that, though.

Answer (score 3):

To dig into the Linux kernel you need a *solid* background in C. At least grab a tutorial (like http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html) and work through it. The Linux gurus use all sorts of hairraising constructions, both for efficiency (code that is run many thousands of times a day on millions of devices), to abstract common constructions that are complex and error-prone to write out by hand, and for helping creating architecture-independent code. Macros certainly are a basic tool here, and they are a somewhat arcane corner of C. Beware, the kernel also uses all sort of GCC-only extensions freely.